# Is the crunchbang openbox autostart script simply a bash script

Tags: debian, openbox, crunchbang

Is the crunchbang openbox autostart script simply a bash script, thus concluding I can put anything bashy in there?? And when is the script executed (e.g. login after rc.local)?

System: Crunchbang Waldorf on Debian Wheezy net install

Comment: If you are talking about this: http://crunchbanglinux.org/pastebin/1054, then yes.

Comment: duhhh should have read the first line! 
## Openbox autostart.sh Thanks @Ketan

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes autostart is a shell (not necessarily bash) script that launches after you log into the GUI. You can launch programs or custom scripts or write them right in the autostart file. I would suggest writing the scripts separately and then launching them with autostart.

Comment: thanks, and yeah not necessarily bash of course, but bash is the most common shell.